# How to distinguish Coulomb and radiative parts of the electromagnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, photons, quantum-electrodynamics, coulombs-law

In classical electromagnetism, the EM field can be described by a 4-potential $A^\mu$. This potential describes two different phenomena.

1. Static fields: A static charge $q$ at fixed position $r_0$ will have attached a Coulomb field $A^0=\frac{q}{|r-r_0|}$.
2. Radiative fields: These are wave solutions to Maxwell's equations that are not attached to any charges, necesarily.

These two seem to be different in that static fields are fully determined by the matter degrees of freedom while radiative fields need to be determined independently. In other words, if we want to count degrees of freedom, or build a phase space, the static fields don't really matter.

Is there a covariant way to distinguish between the two? That is: given a 4-potential $A^\mu$, is there an operation we can apply to it to find just it's static piece or just it's radiative piece?

It seems to me that if I do an experiment locally and measure an electromagnetic interaction, I can check if the electric field decays as $1/r^2$ or as $1/r$ and immediately tell them apart but I'm not sure if this applies generally.

EDIT:

I read in this kind of unrelated paper https://arxiv.org/abs/2112.10798 that one way to distinguish bound and radiative fields is using the fact that radiation goes to infinity but "bound fields follow massive particles to future timelike infinity". Is there something more mathematical to say about this? Like a pullback to $\mathscr{I}^+$ or something like that.

Comment: At least in vacuum, the radiative field is the part "on shell", i.e. its Fourier transform has $\omega = |\mathbf{k}|$.

Comment: I've had the same question - see appendix H in Purcell and Morin 3rd edition. Explains it very intuitively. Radiation fields by the way are distinct from Coulomb fields and Bio-Savart fields. The pictures mixing them all up gives the impression that radiation fields are Columb fields that somehow get disconnected from the source. But that's a false view, and the resource I mentioned makes sense of it on an intuitive undergraduate level. Another way is to see the different fields through the magnetic vector potential A, but that's not as intuitive as the resource I mentioned.

Comment: Sorry I believe your question recognized them as distinct fields. And to last part of of question, the resource I mentioned also explains the 1/R and 1/R^2 math, without even making it complicated. In short, the radiative fields don't violate Gauss' law being transverse, yet are necessary as 1/R to get an angle correction needed for field continuity.

Answer (score 1):

What you seem to be after is not that well described as "static" field component vs "radiative" field component, because also field of a uniformly moving particle is fully determined by the state of motion of the particle. So a better distinction would be:

1. the "bound field" component, determined by the state of motion of matter particles at any time (thus this field component is adding no new degrees of freedom), which gives field *due to those particles* in cases where they are at rest or moving uniformly; and
2. the "free field" component, *not determined* by the state of motion of matter particles, which gives the correction to the bound field component needed to obtain the total field (thus this field component *is* adding new degrees of freedom).

We can make this precise by assuming a system of $N$ point charges, interacting electromagnetically. State of motion of the matter is the list of pairs$(\mathbf r_a,\mathbf v_a)$. Let's define the bound field in any frame as sum over all charged particles, where each particle's contribution is the field of an imaginary particle with the same position and velocity as the real particle, but moving uniformly for all time.

Thus

$$
F_{bound}(\mathbf x,t) = \sum_a F_{uniform,(q_a,\mathbf r_a(t),\mathbf v_a(t))}(\mathbf x,t),
$$
where $F_{uniform,(q,\mathbf r,\mathbf v)}$ gives the field due to a point particle with charge $q$, located at $\mathbf r$, moving uniformly with velocity $\mathbf v$ for all time.

One could derive this function from the standard formulae giving electric and magnetic field of a uniformly moving point charge. Those are well-known formulae, however they are usually given in terms of retarded distance to the charge $r_{ret}$, instead of its current position $\mathbf r_a$ and velocity $\mathbf v_a$. The retarded distance to our imaginary particle obeys the relation

$$
r_{a,ret}(t) = \left|\mathbf x - \mathbf R_a\left(t-\frac{r_{a,ret}}{c}\right)\right|
$$
where $\mathbf R_a(t') = \mathbf r_a + \mathbf v_a ( t'-t)$ gives position of the imaginary particle at time $t'$ (so it coincides with the real particle $a$ at the time $t$ and the position $\mathbf r_a$).

Thus we have the equation

$$
r_{a,ret} = \left|\mathbf x - \mathbf r_a + \mathbf v_a \frac{r_{a,ret}}{c}\right|
$$
for the unknown $r_{a,ret}$, which can be solved to get it in terms of $q_a, \mathbf r_a,\mathbf v_a$ and $\mathbf x, t$.

We can then use this to express $F_{uniform,(q_a,\mathbf r_a(t),\mathbf v_a(t))}$ in terms of $q_a,\mathbf r_a,\mathbf v_a$ and $\mathbf x, t$.   (I leave this as an exercise for the reader).

Thus we get explicit expression of the bound field component in terms of state variables of the matter particles. Then we can define the free field component simply as the remainder:
$$
F_{free} = F - F_{bound}.
$$

The same procedure could be done using the electric potential $\varphi$ and vector potential $\mathbf A$, instead of the field matrix $F$, but these potentials have the disadvantage that they always carry non-physical (artificial, superfluous) degrees of freedom. This makes them inappropriate for describing this split, if we want to have a quantity describing the bound field component which would be determined by the state of motion of the matter only, and a quantity describing the free field component that would have only the additional new physical degrees of freedom, and not more.

Just as the four-coordinate and four-velocity $r^\mu,u^\mu$ of a point particle carry more degrees of freedom than the physical state of the particle $\mathbf r,\mathbf v$ (due to time components of both four-vectors), the four-potential $A^\mu$ carries more degrees of freedom than the state of the field, due to gauge freedom in the concept of $A$ (which defined constraints on $A$, but not $A$ itself uniquely). Covariant expressions are nice, and gauge freedom allows them, but they are in conflict with having quantities whose real value is identified (one-to-one relationship) with physical state at a given time.

Answer (score -1):

If a distinction ought to be made between "bound" and "free" fields, it is at a purely technical level (e.g. when applying asymptotic analysis to radiation by accelerating point charges, or when solving Maxwell's equations with Green's functions.) In the language of linear partial differential equations, you can think of it simply as separating a particular solution $\phi^*$ to an inhomogeneous PDE (sans boundary conditions) given in terms of Green's functions from the homogeneous "correction" term $\phi_0$ that aligns the sum $\phi^* + \phi_0$ with the prescribed boundary conditions (modulo gauge invariance/symmetry/transformations.)

In the Lorentz (relativistic) gauge, Maxwell's equations can be expressed in terms of the vector potential $A^\mu$ simply as $\square A^\mu = j^\mu$, where $\square \equiv \frac{1}{c^2}\partial_t^2 - \nabla^2$ (or just $\partial_t^2 - \nabla^2$ in 'natural' units*) and $j^\mu$ is the "four current", $(\rho, \vec j)$ (it was this formulation of Maxwell's equations that motivated special relativity.)  Conventionally, the above partial differential equation is solved in free space with the Green function (centered at the origin)
\begin{align*}
G(\vec r,t) \propto \frac{\delta(t - |\vec r| / c)}{|\vec r|},\quad t \geq 0, \quad 0\quad \text{t < 0}
\end{align*}
in 3+1 dimensional spacetimes (the form of the Green function is slightly different in different dimensions, changing the UV and IR structure of theories accordingly.) This can be checked directly by inverting the Fourier transform of $(\vec k^2 - \omega^2)^{-1}$ (which in turn is just $\square^{-1}$ in Fourier space), regularizing the integral near $k^2=\omega^2$ to ensure proper causality (this part is reasonable, but a bit hand-wavy, but the dilemma of what regularizer to use is in part why dynamics that allow rough paths can be so perplexing/interesting.)

In any event, assuming smooth trajectories, a *particular* solution to Maxwell's equations-with-inhomogeneous-source is formally given by
\begin{align*}
A^\mu(x,t) = \int_{\mathbb R^3} d\vec x' \int_{-\infty}^t dt' G(\vec x - \vec x', t - t') j^\mu(x', t')
\end{align*}
From which $\vec B$ and $\vec E$ can be determined from the usual identification with (using the $(+,-,-,-)$ signature) $\nabla \times \vec A$ and $-\nabla A^0$ respectively.  Moreover, while the vector potential generally depends on your choice of gauge, the $E$ and $B$ fields will coincide for any Green function with consistent boundary conditions.  In general, the actual field will be a combination of the above particular solution and a solution to the homogeneous vacuum Maxwell equations chosen to match the boundary conditions of the field on some Cauchy surface (e.g. a constant-time slice with respect to some observer.) Things are a little bit more interesting when the domain includes unbounded charge distributions however, or matter distributions with some non-trivial electromagnetic interaction/constitutive relation (e.g. a conductor or dielectric medium, or a dilute inertial insulating gas with some nontrivial static charge distribution.)

*One deficiency to this choice of unit (where "$\hbar = c = 1$") is that it implicitly ignores the possibility of a spatially varying speed of light, which could theoretically emerge from inhomogeneous source terms applied to the QED Lagrangian through [Infrared Divergences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrared_divergence), and the apparent degeneracy of the QED vacuum state (c.f. Kapec et al, 2017 https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.04311.pdf.)

Comment: So how do you define "bound" field? As the particular solution? This isn't satisfactory, because that field has additional field degrees of freedom, just like the homogeneous solution.

Comment: I'm defining the bound field as the particular solution with respect to a pre-defined choice of Green function (that is compactly supported near t = 0.) Wouldn't the field degrees of freedom depend on the regularity of the solution space?

Comment: What do you mean by "regularity of the solution space"? How would field degrees of freedom depend on that?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have a comment to make. The inhomogeneous solution to Maxwell's equations will itself have a Coulomb piece and a radiative piece. Just in the example of the field of an accelerating point charge, the Lienard-Wiechert expression has a piece that decays as 1/r^2 and becomes the Columb field in the static limit, and another piece that decays as 1/r and vanishes on the static limit. I don't think that separating homogeneous and inhomogeneous pieces is the split I was refering to in my question.

Comment: OK, then the other two possibilities that come to mind are (i) the multipole expansion, and (ii) electromagnetic fields in matter, where you might separate current into "bound" and "free" components (and the associated fields generated similarly.)

Comment: I agree with @P.C.Spaniel, the split into "bound" and "free" field, if it is to mean their contribution to the list of degrees of freedom, is not the same thing as split into a particular solution and a homogeneous solution, because the particular solution has field degrees of freedom(radiation). It seems common to call the Coulomb integral field the "the bound field" but this is only part of the latter, not taking into account the bound magnetic field and dependence of both electric and magnetic field on velocity of the charged source.